# how to find out element has child elements or not in QXmlStreamReader CPP

Tags: c++, xml, qt, qxmlstreamreader

I have a huge Xml file, whose elements can be repetative and can contain number of child elements. I need a generic code which can read all elements and their Child elements without hardcoding.
Note: can use only QXmlStreamReader ,Not QDomDocument.
Thanks !!

```
while (!reader.atEnd())
        {
            QString nodename;

            if (reader.isStartElement())///check if the element has chlid tags
            {
                        nodename = reader.name().toString();
                qDebug() << "NodeName is : " << nodename;
                nodevalue = reader.text().toString();
                qDebug() << "NodeValue is : " << nodevalue;
                p_rootParent->CreateChildElement(nodename,reader.text().toString());

            }
            else
            {
                while (reader.readNextStartElement())
                {
                    nodename = reader.name().toString();
                    qDebug() << "NodeName is : " << nodename;
                    nodevalue = reader.text().toString();
                    qDebug() << "NodeValue is : " << nodevalue;
                    p_rootParent->CreateChildElement(nodename, reader.text().toString());
                }
            }
        }
```

This is the code I have written so far, but its not working, any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What code have you written so far?

Comment: i have added above :)